# How to put .rfa file on forge design automation?

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-designautomation

I want to put file .rfa into Forge DesignAutomation to use function LoadFamily create Special equipment by Revit. I don't know how to put it.
Is it possible to upload the .rfa?
And do i need to configure the activity, bucket or anything else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send any data to Design Automation job, so that includes `rfa` files. You may follow any of our code samples (say [count.delete](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-countdeletewalls-revit)) and modify it's activity definition to add an extra parameter and give it an hardcoded local name.

```json
"inputRFA": {
    "verb": "get",
    "description": "Input Family",
    "localName": "input.rfa"
}
```

When you post your workitem, you can add the `inputRFA` argument to it with a downloadable link corresponding to the file. This will save your file on the worker machine in the working folder with the hardcoded name provided in the activity parameter `input.rfa`.

You may then load the family in your appbundle code using:

```cs
Family family = null;
document.LoadFamily("input.rfa", out family);
```

If your `input.rfa` is always the same for different jobs, you can instead save the family file(s) in the app bundle itself. See some ideas discussed in the [blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/store-template-documents-appbundle).

Comment: I did it this way but there is this link (https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/store-template-documents-appbundle) I am stuck. The .rfa file I uploaded has a Japanese filename but when I upload it to the server it doesn't have the exact path I uploaded. How to fix it? This is my log in workItem : [03/21/2022 09:01:07] T:\Aces\Applications\2a49267f0450062feff0c6fa51de6097.tanpv.DemoTest11[1].package\CBBDesignAutomations.bundle\Contents\SM_A_01_�W���g.rfa

Comment: For a quick workaround, would it be possible to temporarily convert the filename to something simpler, like `a.rfa`?

Comment: @VUNguyenTrongVTID9, I checked WorkItem `2a49267f0450062feff0c6fa51de6097`, the job succeeded. What does you mean "when I upload it to the server it doesn't have the exact path I uploaded"? 
BTW, you don't have to package `RevitAPI.dll` in the appbundles.

Comment: @EmmaZhu My file must be in Japanese, so is there a way to keep it in Japanese?

Comment: @JeremyTammik T tried it successfully with non-Japanese files but i can only use file name japanese

Comment: @VUNguyenTrongVTID9, I understand your file must be in Japanese, but I don't understand what is your issue now. WorkItem `2a49267f0450062feff0c6fa51de6097` succeeded, I don't see any error in this job's log. Please clarify what you want exactly and then we can help. thanks.